# \cdot screen representation in LyX

Tags: lyx, times

I just had my first experience with LyX 2.1.3. To my (unpleasant) surprise, a `\cdot` command is rendered indistinguishable from a `\times` command in the on-screen preview (as a cross, that is). Up until LyX 2.0 a `\cdot` was a dot and a `\times` was a cross. Can I get the 2.0 preview style back?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Linux? Try `sudo apt-get install latex-xft-fonts`

Comment: If possible try to update to version 2.1.4 and install the fonts I just recommended. If it does not help, you might want to [report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lyx/+bug/1391544) [this](http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/4150) [somewhere](http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/5784) [over](http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/5398) [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lyx/+bug/245337?comments=all).

Comment: I'm running a debian testing distribution, and 2.1.3 is the latest version offered. The package latex-xft-fonts could not be located by apt-get. But thanks for the tip anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you so much, LaRiFaRi! You saved me a lot of frustration. While your suggestion did not solve my problem right away, it put me on the right track. Browsing the package list in Synaptic, I noticed the package 'fonts-lyx' (true-type versions of some TeX fonts used by LyX). Installing that package solved the problem. It should be installed by default, if you ask me.

Comment: `apt-cache show lyx` shows that `fonts-lyx` is "recommended". How did you install LyX? If you did "sudo apt-get install lyx", then all recommended packages are set to install by default. They are only *not* installed if you do `sudo apt-get --no-install-recommends lyx`. I don't recall how it works if you installed LyX through Synaptic or the .deb directly.